# How to change array key value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to extract word counts of html documents located in a folder.

```
<?php

$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('fulltext/course'));
$fulltext_course_files = array();

foreach ($rii as $f) {
    if ($f->isDir()) {
        continue;
    } else {

        $st = strip_tags(strtolower(file_get_contents($f)));
        $swc = str_word_count($st, 1);
        $fulltext_course_files[] = array_count_values($swc);
    }
}


print_r($fulltext_course_files);
?>
```

this code displays words and frequencies in each document. But array index is numeric which I want it to be filename.

```
print_r($fulltext_course_files);
```

shows some like that

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cs] => 7 [home] => 1 [page] => 1 [systems] => 2 [programming] => 1 [and] => 5 [operating] => 2 [practicum] => 1 ....
```

But I want

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cs] => 7 [home]...
```

to be

```
Array ( ["file1.html"] => Array ( [cs] => 7 [home]...
```

I have tried

```
$fulltext_course_files[$f] = array_count_values($swc);
```

but I got "***Warning: Illegal offset type...***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$fulltext_course_files[] = array_count_values($swc);
```

To

```
$fulltext_course_files[$f->getFilename()] = array_count_values($swc);
```

Comment: I skipped that you were in fact using a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. Corrected the answer to retrieve filename from the object